# daloRADIUS php scripts try to load files in webroot?

Tags: apache-httpd, php

I have just installed FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.21 on a Debian 11 server, as well as daloRADIUS, which is installed in `/var/www/html/daloradius`; the Apache version is 2.4.54. When I try to access the web page, it tells me that `login.php is not found`.

Looking in `/var/www/html/daloradius/index.php`, I can see references to `login.php`, which is in the same directory; however, it seems that apache2 looks for this file in `/var/www/html`, which explains the error and matches what I find in the log files. Is there a place - config file or similar - where I can change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In apache `/etc/apache2sites-enabled` adjust the following:

Change

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
```

to

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/daloradius
```